# Clarification for the proof of uncountability of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, real-numbers

The following is from the *Understanding Analysis* 2nd ed., Stephen Abbot, page 28

> If we let $x_1 = f(1), x_2 = f(2)$ and so on, then our assumption that $f$ is onto means that we can write $\mathbb{R} = \{x_1, x_2, \dots\}$ and be confident that every real number appears somewhere on the list. We will now use the Nested Interval Property to produce a real number that is not there.
> Let $I_1$ be a closed interval that does not contain $x_1$. Next, let $I_2$ be a closed interval, contained in $I_1$ that does not contain $x_2$. The existence of such an $I_2$ **is easy to verify**.

This is a pedantic question, but in this scenario, where we have first assumed that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, how would we verify the existence of $I_2$? Just bluntly exclude $x_2$ from $I_1$? Given that most if not all things in the book so far have been proven, why can we just state this? Is it due to the countability assumption on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is usually taken as this: if $I_1=[a,b]$, then divide $I_1$ into three parts - with a small gap, e.g. into thirds: $[a, a+\frac{b-a}{3}], [a+\frac{b-a}{3}, a+2\frac{b-a}{3}], [a+2\frac{b-a}{3}, b]$. Now forget about the middle interval. If $x_2$ is in the first interval, take the *last* interval to be $I_2$. If $x_2$ is in the last interval, take the *first* interval.If $x_2$ is neither in the first nor in the last interval, take any of them.

Comment: Maybe , I miss something. But would this argument not also apply for rational numbers (which form however a countable set) ?

Comment: @Qwaster Yes this arguemtn would be valid also for rational numbers. However rational numbers don't have the nested interval property.

Comment: @Peter It will work, but then for rational numbers the intersection of the whole collection of intervals may end up being empty. ("Nested Interval Property" is not satisfied.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval $I_1$ is of the form $[a,b]$ for some real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a<b$. If $x_2\notin[a,b]$, you can just take $I_2=I_1$. Now, suppose that $x_2\in[a,b]$. If $x_2\leqslant\frac{a+b}2$, you can take $I_2=\left[\frac{a+2b}3,b\right]$. And, if $x_2\geqslant\frac{a+b}2$, you can take $I_2=\left[a,\frac{2a+b}3\right]$.